# Git versioned WordPress project - why should most files be ignored?

Tags: wordpress, git, workflow, gitignore

I've read multiple questions/articles on which files should be ignored in Git based WordPress project. I get the logic that I should only track folders that contains files being developed by myself - especially my (child) theme and some plugins.

My current workflow is something like this:

1. Install WordPress on my local server
2. Do some basic set-up
3. Initiate Git, do an initial commit with all files added
4. Create .gitignore file, add almost everything except some folders
5. Remove --cached files (stop tracking unwanted files in Git)
6. Do lots of development, commits, pushing to the remote repo

The thing is, when my colleague wants to contribute to the project, he can clone the remote repo. But if I understand correctly, he would end up with up do date theme and plugins, but his install would be based on older core, he would miss every image and so on (since wp-includes, uploads etc. were not tracked).

How to handle this workflow properly? Am I missing something?

Comment: What you said is _almost_ correct.  There most likely are one or more files which were authored by you, but are mainly there to configure your Wordpress project.  Ideally the information in these files would tell the project how to pull in the other non source files.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you suggest? Should I include the steps for synchronisation directly from the production or is there a better way to pull those files?

Answer (score 0):

So this phenomena is not just for wordpress, for many coding applications using vcs git or similar. So basically we have a

```
readMe.md
```

file which contains all the information of how to start a project, if there are images then that should be maintained in some file storage remote , like aws s3 , it provides good file versioning too.
Also this approach is done so that our git to and fro data is reduced just to essentials. I hope my answer helps.